# Credit card processing system for static website

Tags: static, web, credit-card

Is there a website or a service that handles all the credit card processing stuff for a basic static website and sends over the payment to an account? Except for paypal ?

Comment: Card processing for 'a basic static website' is no different to card processing for any other website. Look around and you'll find dozens of q&a's on here for website card processing.

Comment: @PaulG I think there are some meaningful differences.  See the answer below about Stripe, which hinges on whether the site is static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rbs worldpay has equivalent services of what Paypal offers.

You have the option of junior invisible and junior, one of it provides a form for filling up cc information on your behalf, the other allows you to capture cc information on your site and pass over to rbs. That's what I recall.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe was built for website credit card processing.

From their site https://stripe.com/

> Payments for developers - Stripe makes it easy to start accepting
>   credit cards on the web today.

You can find additional documentation at https://stripe.com/docs

Disclaimer: I have no business relationship with Stripe. They just seem like a good fit for what your asking.

Comment: He specifically asked about static sites with no backend.  Can stripe be used for just front-end sites?

Comment: @RoryPerro No. From https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/checkout     `To be absolutely clear on the process, the client-side code—Checkout—securely accepts the card information but does not initiate a payment attempt. The actual charge request is triggered from your server.`